# Delete Pixel Junk Racers first version?

Tags: psn

I own the game Pixel Junk Racers. I am also the owner of the second version, Pixel Junk Racers: 2nd Lap. Both games are very similar, but 2nd Lap offers some improvements, so I do not play with the first version. Is it possible to remove it without corrupting or create problems for the second version?

Comment: Why not just try? You can always re-download it if you run into issues.

Comment: Yes! I'll tried! I wanted to save me re-download by asking if anyone had done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work great! It is therefore possible to remove Pixel Junk Racers (1-1) and keep only the 2nd Lap (1-1a).